# Write a program to calculate the value of an expression step by step in Python:

Tags: python

```
Enter the string “(2 + 3 * 4) / 2 – (3^2 - 3)”. Export:
                     = (2 + 12) / 2 – (3^2 – 3)
                     = 14/2 – (3^2 – 3)
                      = 7 – (3^2 – 3)
                      = 7 – (9 – 3)
                      = 7 – 6
                      = 1
```

How should I deal with such results?

Comment: write a computer algebra system, ...., profit?

Comment: `pyparsing` probably is an answer i guess

Comment: do the work first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that does something slightly like what you asked for:

```
import ast
import copy

expr = "(2 + 3 * 4) / 2 - (3**2 - 3)"
tree = ast.parse(expr,mode="eval")

class EvalLeaves(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_BinOp(self, node):
        match node:
            case ast.BinOp(left=ast.Constant(), right=ast.Constant()):
                return ast.Constant(eval(compile(ast.Expression(ast.fix_missing_locations(node)), "<input>", "eval")))
            case _:
                return ast.BinOp(left=self.visit(node.left),op=node.op,right=self.visit(node.right))

print(expr)
while True:
    new_tree = EvalLeaves().visit(copy.deepcopy(tree))
    if ast.dump(tree) == ast.dump(new_tree):
        break
    tree = new_tree
    print("=", ast.unparse(new_tree))
```

Output:

```
(2 + 3 * 4) / 2 - (3**2 - 3)
= (2 + 12) / 2 - (9 - 3)
= 14 / 2 - 6
= 7.0 - 6
= 1.0
```

Exercises/problems for the reader:

- evaluation order the same as in your example
- uses Python syntax, e.g. `**` for exponentiation rather than `^`